# How to classify a part and it's following 10 parts based on a matching condition?

Tags: google-bigquery

So, I have a table that contains schema like below:

```
**Trace_table:-**
parent : String;
part : String;
local_datetime : Datetime;
trace_number : INT64;  --INT64 of (DDMMYYYYHHMMSS)
parameter : String;
value : INT64;
```

Here's a Sample of data : [Sample_data_part_classification](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_WwKx2_ykwAlvaeMyIt8lbtP3wTnruux9Y-Mj9_KW-I/edit?usp=sharing)

for each datetime there will be 53 parameter and one of it is "Hold", Whenever parameter = "Hold" and value = 0, it is considered **bad** and the next following 10 parts will also be called as **bad**.

This should be calculated per part. ( partition by Parent, part)

Firstly I have tried numbering each datetime and then added a if condition where parameter = "Hold" and value = 0 as **Bad**. But it will be only added against that field and not the other parameters of same time. They also should be marked as **Bad**. Can anyone give me a tip?

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parent,part,parameter) AS row_num,
       CASE WHEN parameter = "Hold" AND value = 0 THEN "Bad" END AS Part_classification
FROM sample_data)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

I could not get past this and think of other functions, I tried Lead function but did not work.

```
**Output table:-**
parent : String;
part : String;
local_datetime : Datetime;
trace_number : INT64;
parameter : String;
value : INT64;
part_condition: String;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and show some work. create a column `bad` with the condition you described. Then specify the ordering of your table and the fixed part. The solution will be the use of a window function `over (order by yourcol1 ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW  )`   https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/window-function-calls

Comment: added sample data. Through window function can we mark some rows? I thought we can only do aggregations over a window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A window function does the job.

```sql
with sample_data as (select 
"parent1" as parent,    "part1" as part, * from  unnest([struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC") as local_datetime
,20221220184445 as trace_number,"parameter1" as parameter,10 as value,1 as Row_number),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter2",70,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter3",70,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter4",35,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter5",70,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter6",9953,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter7",120,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter8",120,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter9",120,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter10",120,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter11",14,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter12",120,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter13",10,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter14",185,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter15",35,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter16",70,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter17",60,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter18",130,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter19",242.4,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter20",65,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter21",4525608,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter22",0,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter23",185,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter24",271786,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter25",245,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter26",250.5,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter27",35,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter28",35,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter29",242.8,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter30",55,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter31",194.4,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter32",43996,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter33",2486,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter34",24,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter35",6656901,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter36",227.2,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter37",15,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter38",15,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter39",235,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter40",210,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter41",70,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter42",221786,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter43",220,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter44",250,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter45",70,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter46",15,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter47",687934,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter48",35,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter49",250,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"Hold",0,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter51",70,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter52",231,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:44:00 UTC"),20221220184445,"parameter53",0,1),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter1",10,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter2",70,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter3",70,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter4",35,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter5",70,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter6",10443,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter7",120,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter8",120,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter9",120,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter10",120,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter11",14,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter12",120,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter13",10,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter14",185,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter15",35,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter16",70,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter17",60,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter18",130,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter19",244.3,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter20",65,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter21",4568142,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter22",0,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter23",185,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter24",3027011,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter25",245,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter26",250.5,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter27",35,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter28",35,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter29",240.5,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter30",55,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter31",193.4,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter32",54632,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter33",44593,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter34",14,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter35",6546586,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter36",226.7,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter37",15,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter38",15,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter39",235,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter40",210,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter41",70,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter42",2527011,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter43",220,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter44",250,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter45",70,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter46",15,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter47",6648763,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter48",35,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter49",250,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"Hold",0,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter51",70,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter52",231.3,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:45:00 UTC"),20221220184532,"parameter53",0,2),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter1",10,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter2",70,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter3",70,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter4",35,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter5",70,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter6",45962,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter7",120,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter8",120,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter9",120,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter10",120,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter11",14,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter12",120,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter13",10,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter14",185,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter15",35,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter16",70,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter17",60,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter18",130,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter19",245.1,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter20",65,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter21",46.25,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter22",0,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter23",185,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter24",1849188,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter25",245,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter26",249.7,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter27",35,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter28",35,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter29",242.8,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter30",55,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter31",191.9,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter32",50287,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter33",2504,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter34",14,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter35",7038483,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter36",225.8,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter37",15,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter38",15,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter39",235,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter40",210,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter41",70,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter42",1349188,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter43",220,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter44",250,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter45",70,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter46",15,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter47",7006836,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter48",35,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter49",250,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"Hold",3,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter51",70,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter52",231.3,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter53",0,3),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter1",10,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:46:00 UTC"),20221220184622,"parameter2",70,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter3",70,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter4",35,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter5",70,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter6",45962,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter7",120,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter8",120,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter9",120,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter10",120,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter11",14,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter12",120,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter13",10,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter14",185,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter15",35,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter16",70,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter17",60,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter18",130,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter19",245.1,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter20",65,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter21",46.25,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter22",0,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter23",185,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter24",1849188,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter25",245,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter26",249.7,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter27",35,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter28",35,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter29",242.8,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter30",55,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter31",191.9,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter32",50287,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter33",2504,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter34",14,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter35",7038483,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter36",225.8,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter37",15,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter38",15,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter39",235,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter40",210,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter41",70,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter42",1349188,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter43",220,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter44",250,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter45",70,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter46",15,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter47",7006836,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter48",35,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter49",250,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"Hold",3,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter51",70,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter52",231.3,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 18:55:00 UTC"),20221220185522,"parameter53",0,4),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter1",10,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter2",70,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter3",70,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter4",35,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter5",70,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter6",45962,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter7",120,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter8",120,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter9",120,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter10",120,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter11",14,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter12",120,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter13",10,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter14",185,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter15",35,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter16",70,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter17",60,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter18",130,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter19",245.1,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter20",65,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter21",46.25,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter22",0,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter23",185,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter24",1849188,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter25",245,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter26",249.7,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter27",35,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter28",35,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter29",242.8,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter30",55,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter31",191.9,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter32",50287,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter33",2504,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter34",14,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter35",7038483,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter36",225.8,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter37",15,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter38",15,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter39",235,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter40",210,5),
struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 19:46:00 UTC"),20221220194622,"parameter41",70,5),

struct(timestamp("2022-12-20 21:58:00 UTC"),20221220215822,"parameter53",0,13)
])),
CTE AS(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parent,part,parameter) AS row_num,
       CASE WHEN parameter = "Hold" AND value = 0 THEN "Bad" END AS Part_classification
FROM sample_data),
CTE2 as (
Select *,
max(Part_classification) over last10 as Bad_label
from CTE
window last10 as (partition by part order by local_datetime,trace_number  ROWS BETWEEN 10 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW  )
)

Select * from CTE2
order by part, local_datetime,trace_number
```

Comment: Hey sam, thank you so much, It worked. The window function. I thought the max,min,avg are only for some integer aggregation only and did not check out further. However, I modified a little bit because in your code you were only labelling the parameter, Usually it should be labelled per trace number. Thank you so much anyway.